# Not able to find my element which is text between span tag

Tags: java, html, selenium

I'm using Selenium Web Driver for automation and with this new app, I'm not able to find element by normal method. 
My code looks like:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/md-sidenav/md-list[1]/md-list-item[2]/button")).click();
```

---

And I want to click on 'Views'. Need some help, I have tried following methods for xpath:

```
//span[contains(@class, 'ng-binding ng-scope') and normalize-space()='Data']

//div[1]/md-sidenav/descendant::span[text()='Data']/button ---- no success
```

When I'm using :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/md-sidenav/md-list[1]/md-list-item[2]/button")).click();
```

Above code works but I don't want to use item[x], because they will changes very often.

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: Please share a piece of your html code

Comment: I think site you are testing looks in angular js , is that correct?

Comment: Please Share the html snippet code if it is angular js app then kindly refer this link for info.                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557644/testing-angularjs-application-with-selenium

Comment: Share your html code at first